# Multiple url for same content in umbraco

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo, umbraco, canonical-link

Im using Umbraco 6.1.5. I need a better structure of my site, from SEO point of view.
But it seems like umbraco generating too many links for the same content. Which is not good from SEO perspective.

for e.g. for single content i will have multiple url's like below:

id.aspx

id

id/

folder/node.aspx

folder/node

its creating 4 pages with same content. which will effect in google indexing.
above pages will be indexed as duplicate.

Can any body suggest me , how can i get rid of multiple url's for the same content in Umbraco.

I know few of the methods like 301 redirect and canonical .
but not sure which one will be better to use with umbraco. or i use both?

if yes , then how to use 301 redirect and canonical url in umbraco

Answer (score 3):

If you never link to them then google can't know about those "extra" links so it's not going to hurt your SEO.

Of course you can always included the canonical meta tag in each page and Google will be happy with that and ignore the alternative versions.

If you really want to try then have a look at the [UrlRewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for IIS, you could at least rewrite the .aspx version (just strip the .aspx).

I don't know why you would ever link to the "/id" (so: site.com/3301) version from anywhere but if you do then you could have a look at implementing your own HttpModule to get the NiceUrl of the page and do a 301 redirect to it.

Again, all this is totally unnecessary as long as you don't have an `<a href="...>` link to the alternative URLs and don't link to them in your sitemap xml or robots.txt. Google doesn't know about links until you advertise to the world that they exist.

Comment: sounds good, that unless i use link of my page, google will not count. but still as a safer way, page is one, so where to write? rel=canonical, where to use 301 redirection and any such stuffs? Please suggest

Comment: I don't know what you mean? Again: if you never create a link to id.aspx, id, id/  and folder/node.aspx then Google will only ever know about "folder/node" so you don't have to tell Google it's the canonical link.